# Update Plotly Y axis range after setting X axis range

Tags: plotly

I am graphing time series data with a long history using Plotly, and by default I would like the chart to be zoomed in on the most recent data. I can do this by setting the `range` argument of the `update_xaxes` method. However, the Y axis is still set based on the entire history of the data, whereas I would like it calculated on the actually visible data. For instance, in the code below the Y axis will be set to a range of (0,100), even though the visible data only starts at 50 (so expecting a range more like 50-100 on the Y axis). If the user were to then later scroll or zoom the X axis I would want the Y axis to continue to update to accommodate the visible data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(n), 'y': np.arange(n)})
fig = px.line(df, x='x', y='y')
fig.update_xaxes(range=(50,99))
fig.show()
```

Comment: You can also use fig.update_yaxes to update the range of y?

Comment: But then do I need to re-calculate the appropriate range myself? I would also prefer this work with faceted plots, each with their own Y axes range, so hoping there is a simpler way.

Comment: You can read about selection event and use the bounds of selected area to be your ranges. https://plotly.com/python/v3/selection-events/

Answer (score 3):

If you want the yaxis range to dynamically resize depending on the visible data, you'll either need to use `Dash` or a `FigureWidget` which support callbacks.

As @Phoenix suggested in the comments, you could use a FigureWidget using a Jupyter notebook. Here is an example (with the dynamically calculated yaxis range displayed in the title for debugging purposes):

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.offline as py

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

py.init_notebook_mode()

n = 100
df = pd.DataFrame({'x': np.arange(n), 'y': np.arange(n)})
fig = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=df['x'], y=df['y'])])
fig.update_xaxes(range=(50,99))

def zoom(xrange):
    xrange_zoom_min, xrange_zoom_max = fig.layout.xaxis.range[0], fig.layout.xaxis.range[1]
    yaxis_range = df.loc[df['x'].between(xrange_zoom_min,xrange_zoom_max), 'y']
    padding = (yaxis_range.max() - yaxis_range.min()) / 16
    
    fig.layout.yaxis.range = [yaxis_range.min() - padding, yaxis_range.max() + padding]
    fig.layout.title = f"Setting new range to {fig.layout.yaxis.range}"

fig.layout.on_change(zoom, 'xaxis.range')
```

[image]

Comment: I do not think you need this line `scatter = fig.data[0]`

Comment: You can use only `zoom(xrange)` without layout.

Comment: @Phoenix oh good point, thanks for the corrections

Comment: Another point, this solution works only if the `xrange_zoom_min` and `xrange_zoom_max` are included in the dataframe, otherwise it does not work. Try to zoom in multiple times, you will find the padding of y does not work anymore.